# Solving $N(A^T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

If I'm trying to find the vectors spanning $N(A^T)$ for matrix 
$ A= \begin{bmatrix} 1 &2 &1 &1 \\ -1 & 0 &3 &4 \\ 2 &2 &-2 &-3 \end{bmatrix} $

Note:N(A^T) is the left nullspace

This is what I've done...

1) Find $A^T$...

$ A^T= \begin{bmatrix} 1 &-1 &2 \\ 2 & 0 &2  \\ 1 &3 &-2 \\ 1 & 4 & -3\end{bmatrix} $

2) Get to Reduced echelon form...

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 &0 &1 \\ 0 & 1 &-1 \\ 0 &0 &0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} $

3)Solve for vector...

$x_1=-x_3$
$x_2=x_3$

so $ V=(-1, 1,1)$  Is this all I need to do/Is this right?

Also could someone explain what's the difference between finding a vector spanning spanning $N(A^T)$ and giving a basis for the subspace $N(A^T)$. Are these just the same processes? Since when finding basis for the subspace $N(A^T)$. for

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &2 &-1& 0 \\ 2 & 4 & -1 & -1  \\ \end{bmatrix}$

I got...

$A^T=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &2\\ 2 & 4 \\ -1 & -1\\ 0&-1  \\ \end{bmatrix}$

Then...

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 &2\\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\\ 0& 0  \\ \end{bmatrix}$

so $x_1=-2x_2$
so N(A^T): (-2,1) right?